# How to popup window on MapLongClickListener?

Tags: android, google-maps, popupwindow

I want to make a popup window when long clicking on a map, here is my codes and popup.xml:
however the popupwindow didn't appear and the `Log` tells that the window is showing. Besides, there are many versions of the `Constructor` and `showAtLocation` functions and I am not very clear about the differences between them. Can someone find the mistakes in my code ? Thank you very much!

```
private void init()
{
    mGMap = ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    if( mGMap != null )
    {
        mGMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mGMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mGMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mGMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mGMap. setOnMapLongClickListener (new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View popup_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popup_view);              
                View parent =  ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView();
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                int xoff = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2 - popupWindow.getWidth() / 2;
                // 使其聚集
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                // 设置允许在外点击消失
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, xoff, 0);
                if(popupWindow.isShowing()){
                    Log.i(mainActivity.toString(), "pop up is showing");
                }
                popupWindow.update();
            }
        });
    }
```

And the following is my popup.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_time_tag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/loc_date" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_diary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/location_time_tag">
    </ListView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listview_diary"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />    
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/add_text_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/add_note"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="写日记"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/del_text_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/add_text_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="删日记"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as logs are saying that your popup window is open means you are adding wrong context for window.It means window is opened but in some other activity or in some other class.You should test applying proper context to window.

Comment: I have tried the `MainActivity`, the popup still didn't show. May be it is not the problem...

Comment: ok than try mapview.invalidate() in your code after adding the window as you have to redraw the map after adding any viewing object to it.

Comment: I change the context to `MapFragment.getActivity()`; and the most important, i forgot `setHeight()` and `setWidth()`, Problem solved. thanks for u help.